# If $X \geq 0$ is a r.v. with a mean of $a > 0$ and variance $ac>0$, what is the limiting distribution of $\frac{Y}{a}$ as $a \to \infty$?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X \geq 0$ is a r.v. with a mean of $a > 0$ and variance $ac>0$, with $c>0$, what is the limiting distribution of $\frac{X}{a}$ as $a \to \infty$? I have tried to use the Delta method but cannot seem to formulate the problem correctly. Would anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried computing the mean and variance of $X/a$?

Comment: Yes, I got that the mean is 1 and the variance is $\frac{c}{a}$, which asymptotically means that it goes to a mean 1 and variance 0 distribution, which implies that the distribution should be a point mass function centered at 1. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Can you show that $X/a$ converges in probability to the constant $1$? (Recall that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, to the same limit.)

Comment: Hi, would this proof suffice? Using Chebyshev's inequality, for every $\epsilon >0$, $P\left(\mid \frac{X}{a}-1 \mid \geq \epsilon \right) \leq \frac{c}{a \epsilon^2}$. Hence, as $a \to \infty$, $P\left(\mid \frac{X}{a}-1 \mid \geq \epsilon \right) \leq 0$, but since probability must be nonnegative, must have that $P\left(\mid \frac{X}{a}-1 \mid \geq \epsilon \right) \to 0$, which implies from definition of convergence of probability that $\frac{X}{a} \to 1$ in probability. Do you see anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: Your argument looks fine.